# Spectral radius of a matrix of bounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

If $a,b,c,d$ denote four bounded operators on Banach spaces, let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Can the spectral radius of $A$ be linked to those of $a,b,c,d$ ?

For example, if $c=0$, then I would guess that $r(A)=\max(r(a),r(b))$, is that the case ?
Also, can this be generalized to a 3x3 matrix ? Or to a $n\times n$ matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c = 0$ then the spectrum of $A$ is contained in the union of the spectra of $a$ and $d$.  In fact, if $a-\lambda I$ and $d - \lambda I$ are invertible then
$$ \pmatrix{a-\lambda I & b\cr 0 & d - \lambda I}^{-1} = \pmatrix{ (a-\lambda I)^{-1} & - (a - \lambda I)^{-1} b (d - \lambda I)^{-1}\cr 0 & (d-\lambda I)^{-1}}$$
This generalizes to $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices of operators, since e.g. you can write
$$ \pmatrix{a & b & c\cr 0 & d & e\cr 0 & 0 & f} = \pmatrix{A & B\cr 0 & f}$$
where
$$ A = \pmatrix{a & b\cr 0 & d},\ B = \pmatrix{c\cr e\cr}$$

Comment: How do you compute the inverse ? Like a regular matrix ?
And if $c\neq0$, you can search for eigenvalues for the matrix as normal, that is computing the characteristic polynomial ?

Comment: Check that the inverse works by multiplying (both ways).  There is no characteristic polynomial, and members of the spectrum are not necessarily eigenvalues: these are Banach space operators.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. So there are no real way to know the spectral radius for a general $3\times 3$ or even a $2\times 2$ matrix, this has to be dealt case by case ?